# Could not find or load main class gradle 7.0 spring-boot 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I just made an update from spring boot version "2.2.1.RELEASE" to 2.5.6 and along with that I also updated the gradle version to 7.0. Before the update everything worked fine but after the update it seems that the bootRun task doesn't find the main class.

This is the error received:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 12 actionable tasks: 12 executed
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.TestApplication
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I ve followed the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application and I have the following  **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.5.6'
    }
    repositories {
    // ..
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath("net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.15")
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.11.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.git-version'

def mapStructVersion = "1.3.0.Final"
def swaggerVersion = "1.6.3"
def junitVersion = "4.13.2"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated/source/apt/main"
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated/source/apt/main"
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "seconds"
}

repositories {
    // ...
}

task preBuild {
    delete "${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated/source/apt/main"
}

build.dependsOn preBuild

configurations {
    developmentOnly.extendsFrom compile
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

/**
 * Fix extension/file too long issue under windows
 */
task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.developmentOnly
    archiveAppendix = 'pathing'

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.developmentOnly.files.collect {
                it.toURI().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}

/**
 * With gradle 7, a duplicate strategy must be set in order to not encountering error during copy operation.
 * Solution: EXCLUDE strategy do not allow duplicates by ignoring subsequent items to be created at the same path.
 */
processIntegrationTestResources {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

bootRun {
    main = 'com.test.TestApplication'
    dependsOn pathingJar
    doFirst {
        classpath = files(sourceSets.main.output.files, pathingJar.archiveFile)
    }
    def debugPort = project.properties["${project.name}.debugPort"]
    if (debugPort) {
        jvmArgs = ["-Xdebug", "-Xnoagent", "-Djava.compiler=NONE", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debugPort}"]
    }
    if (System.getProperty("LOG_PATH") == null) {
        System.setProperty("LOG_PATH", project.projectDir.getCanonicalPath() + "/log")
    }
    if (System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") == null) {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "some-profile")
    }
    if (System.getProperty("servicelayer.rrLogHumanReadable") == null) {
        System.setProperty("servicelayer.rrLogHumanReadable", "true")
    }
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

def compileDependencies = [
        "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.0.4",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache",
        "io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:${swaggerVersion}",
        "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0",
        "org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.6.3",
        'org.flywaydb:flyway-core',
        "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapStructVersion}",
        "com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine",
        'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60'
]

// defined some dependencies. Not relevant

dependencies {
    implementation compileDependencies
    providedRuntime providedRuntimeDependencies
    testImplementation testCompileDependencies
}
```

I tried both ways, from command line and from ide (IntelliJ)

```
clean bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active="some-profile"
```

Comment: It could be helpful to add the whole `build.gradle` file (removing only sensitive data).

Comment: Ok, I will do that

Comment: Please mention how you are running the application as well: command-line, IDE...

Comment: I ve updated the details

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the issue has been inside the **task pathingJar**.

Before:

```
  task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.developmentOnly
    archiveAppendix = 'pathing'

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.developmentOnly.files.collect {
                it.toURI().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

After:

```
task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    archiveAppendix = 'pathing'

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect {
                it.toURI().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

So the solution has been to change the following two lines of code

`dependsOn configurations.developmentOnly` -> `dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath`

`attributes "Class-Path": configurations.developmentOnly.files.collect` {...} -> `attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect {...}`

Long story short is that somehow another tasks interfered with this task on **developmentOnly** scope and I had to change it to **runtimeClasspah**

**Edit:**

Another issue might be inside of **bootRun** task. You can define the package where is the main class.

```
bootRun {
    main = 'edu.somepacke.MyMainClass'
    dependsOn pathingJar
    doFirst {
        classpath = files(sourceSets.main.output.files, pathingJar.archiveFile)
    }
    //extra logic
}
```